# How can i save objects, but not overwrite in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, object, bookmarks, favorite

**Hello :)**

How can i save objects, but not overwrite in Objective C,

i tried NSUserDefaults but when i add object, it will overwrite !

how can i prevent this, because i am trying to create a favorites in my app or bookmarks,

but i don't know how to save those objects i am trying to save.

This is when i am trying to save.

```
NSUserDefaults *favorite = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[favorite setObject:saveTip forKey:@"saveTipFavorite"];

[favorite synchronize];
```

But i overwrite every time i push add to favorite button in my app !

And i don't want it to overwrite, but make a new object and append it.

I hope you understand me :)

Answer (score 2):

It is overwriting because there can only be one object per key, and you are changing it each time. What you want to do, is store an array instead of a single object, and set that as a key in your user defaults.

Initialization:

```
NSMutableArray *objectArray;
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *oldSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"savedArray"];
if (oldSavedArray != nil)
   objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
else
   objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Notice we are converting from `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` because the user defaults can only store the immutable (`NSArray`) version.

Then to add an item:

```
[objectArray addObject:whatever];
[currentDefaults setObject:objectArray forKey:@"savedArray"];
```

If this is something you will be doing a lot (tons of data), you may consider using Core Data instead, it will be faster. `NSUserDefaults` is not really meant for storing heavy data.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, so the last conversion isn't necessary; `-setObject:forKey:` will accept the mutable array just fine (though it will of course be stored immutably and come back out as a plain `NSArray`).

Answer (score 0):

The object you save can be an array.  Create an array to save the tips and make that the object given to `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is fine for simple stuff, but if you want your App to handle significant amount of data, you will want to start using `CoreData`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Not only will this solve your saving problem, it will also make it easier to manipulate your data.

Comment: My app is only a tip app, showing tip from web... a object contains name, description, timestamp, can i use NSUserDefaults for that or is it too much data. :)

Comment: You should be fine going with NSUserDefaults.  I was just suggesting core data in case you needed to include multiple objects, and more than one of the same type of object.  Coredata has steeper learning curve as well, so maybe keep it in mind for your next big project.